# jQuery: подсчет количества отмеченных чекбоксов только для выбранного элемента

Tags: jquery, функции, this, each

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как привязать функцию `displayCount` к текущему `.filter_item`? Все что в `$('.filter_item').each(function() {` работает корректно, но функция `displayCount() {` применяется ко всем `.count` на странице, которых несколько на странице (по одному в каждом `.filter_item`).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    
    var count = 0;
    
    $('.filter_item').each(function() {
        
        count = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input:checked').length;
        displayCount();  
        
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input').bind('click' , function(e, a) {  
            if (this.checked) {
                count += a ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                count += a ? 1 : -1;
            }
            displayCount();
        });
    });
    
    function displayCount() {
        if (count == 0) {
            $('.count').hide();
            } else {
            $('.count').show().text(count);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Можно передавать элемент в функцию  и с ним уже делать что хотите.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Вот как тут сделать ```.filter_item``` элементом...если верно вопрос ставлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так поробуйте

```
jQuery(function($) {

    
    $('.filter_item').each(function() {
        let that = this;
        let count = 0;
        count = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input:checked').length;
        displayCount.call(that, count);  
        
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input').bind('click' , function(e, a) {  
            if (this.checked) {
                count += a ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                count += a ? 1 : -1;
            }
            displayCount.call(that, count);
        });
    });
    
    function displayCount(count) {
        if (count == 0) {
            $('.count', this).hide();
            } else {
            $('.count', this).show().text(count);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас при клике по чекбоксу в первом ```.filter_item``` в нем же появляется ```count``` - это ок, но если открыть второй  ```.filter_item``` и кликнуть там по чекбоксу, то плюсует во второй ```.filter_item``` и из первого.

Comment: Да щя порешаем.

Comment: Было бы здорово, я уже голову сломал)

Comment: Я уже изменил если что